# PDO: SQLite INSERT does not get saved

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, sql-insert

I created some tables with the following code:

```
$db = new PDO(SQLITE_PATH);
$statement = $db->prepare('CREATE TABLE States (name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);');
$statement->execute();
$statement = $db->prepare('CREATE TABLE Events (DBID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , CalID INT, start INT, end INT, state VARCHAR(25), FOREIGN KEY(state) REFERENCES States(name));');
$statement->execute();
```

And created an entry "Wochenende" in the table "States".

When i want to insert an entry into the "Events" table with the following code:

```
$from_timestamp = strtotime(date('c'));
$to_timestamp = strtotime(date('c', time()+100000));

$query = 'INSERT INTO Events (CalID,start,end,state) VALUES (:CALID, :START, :END, :STATE);';
$statement = $db->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
if (!$statement) {
        print_r($db->errorInfo());
}
$statement->execute(array(':CALID' => get_highest_calid($db), ':START' => $from_timestamp, ':END' => $to_timestamp, ':STATE' => 'Wochenende'));
```

no error is returned, still no entry is in the database.

Comment: I haven't done any php in decades. Do you need to do a commit?

Comment: @BillBell i tried to use sql transactions, but it did not work either. Also the request to put an entry into the "States" table worked without transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the result of the [`errorInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) method after calling `execute()` shows this error message:

> NOT NULL constraint failed: Events.DBID

It's declared as `DBID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` so why doesn't it just add the next sequential number automatically?

According to the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid):

> A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an integer primary key if the declared type name is exactly "INTEGER".

So you need to change your column definition to `DBID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

---

***Bonus Information:***

Enable [PDO exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) so that these problems become fatal errors, and you don't need to manually call `errorInfo()`:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

This throws the following exception and halts execution:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: Events.DBID in ...

---

***Bonus Information 2:***

Since you are declaring foreign keys, you'll need to enable support for them at runtime as [foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards compatibility)](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable):

```
$db->exec('pragma foreign_keys = ON');
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thank you very much.